# How to Empty Lines?

Tags: python

I ran into a problem while trying to put lines from a .txt file into a list. I know you get extra lines when you do this, so I used line.split() to take out the trailing lines.

When I did this, the words I was trying to read became weirdly formatted. This is what it looked like...

```
['word']
```

Do any of you know how to take out the trailing lines without having this happen?

Comment: Did you try joining back after?

Comment: If by trailing lines you mean empty lines, why just not checking for empty lines?

Comment: `[]` shows that you've got a list, in this case a list with a single item, the string `'word'`. If you look at the documentation of the `split` function (you can execute `help(''.split)` in Python, or Google for the documentation) you'll see that it returns a list of strings. But `split` will split on whitespace by default, not only on newline characters. Try using `splitlines` instead, or use a construction like `for line in file:`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just read all of lines with `readlines()` function and then you can get the n last line with reverse indexing : `lines[-n:]` and as says in comment its better to call the built-in `list` of open file handle !

```
with open('test_file.txt','r') as f :
 lines =list(f)
```

or

```
with open('test_file.txt','r') as f :
 lines =f.readlines()
```

Comment: or even better just call list on the open file handle

Comment: I actually ended up using the strip() function. Thanks for all the help!